# Get range of adjacent rows with the same value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as below. The first column is positions and the last is level. I want to output the range of rows with the same number in adjacent rows. Anything with '2' should be ignored. Can you help

The input:

```
 1          3
10000       3
20000       3
30000       1
40000       2
50000       2
60000       2
70000       3
80000       1
90000       1

The output
 1-  2999 3
3000-3999 1
7000-7999 3
8000-9999 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method using the chaning functions of `dplyr`. Here's the sample data

```
dd <- structure(list(pos = c(1L, 10000L, 20000L, 30000L, 40000L, 50000L, 
  60000L, 70000L, 80000L, 90000L), level = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("pos", "level"), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -10L))
dd <- dd[order(dd$pos), ]  #make sure its sorted by position
```

If the difference to your next pos is always 10000, you can do

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% arrange(pos) %>% 
    mutate(run=cumsum(c(0,diff(level))!=0)) %>% 
    subset(level!=2) %>% 
    group_by(run) %>%
    summarise(level=max(level), start=min(pos), end=max(pos)+9999) %>%
    select(-run)

#   level start   end
# 1     3     1 29999
# 2     1 30000 39999
# 3     3 70000 79999
# 4     1 80000 99999
```

otherwise

```
dd %>% arrange(pos) %>% 
    mutate(run=cumsum(c(0,diff(level))!=0), nextpos=lead(pos)) %>% 
    subset(level!=2) %>% 
    group_by(run) %>%
    summarise(level=max(level), start=min(pos), end=max(nextpos)-1) %>%
    select(-run)

#   level start   end
# 1     3     1 29999
# 2     1 30000 39999
# 3     3 70000 79999
# 4     1 80000    NA
```

can calculate the distance to the next group for all but the last group.

Comment: OK that first answer is pretty much what I wanted. For fear of being shouted at can I add a twister? What if there is another column called home. Each home has start and end positions so that I'm hoping to get the range start and end positions specific to home. Ive put the examples in the edited code above

Comment: @user3632206 `group_by(home)` at the top (right after `dd %>% `) doesn't do?